# Error: error contacting notary server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am puzzled how docker and Notary work together. I can not sign image

```
docker pull nginx:latest
```

got

```
Error: error contacting notary server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I followed these steps

```
git clone https://github.com/theupdateframework/notary
cd notary $ docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
mkdir -p ~/.notary && cp cmd/notary/config.json cmd/notary/root-ca.crt ~/.notary
```

What root-ca.crt represents? How to check this?
Does the error means the client does not recognize the issuer of the certificate and considers the certificate to be invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root-ca.crt` file is used to establish trust between your Docker client and the Notary server.

Your problem is that the Docker client does not recognize the issuer of the certificate (Notary server) and considers the certificate to be invalid. The reason being that it is not signed by a trusted certificate authority (the default trust on your system)

We gonna tell docker to trust the root CA certificate used by the Notary server. first we gonna create the directory needed for Docker: `sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/your.notary.server.url:4443` then we copy the `root-ca.crt` to it `sudo cp cmd/notary/root-ca.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/your.notary.server.url:4443/ca.crt` restart Docker and it should work.

Comment: This works but I can not run container.

Comment: docker -D run -d --name id identidock
DEBU[0000] reading certificate directory: /home/miki/.docker/tls/notary.docker.io

Comment: I will post new question later.

Comment: check if you have pull the container